# How to make a software resolution independent in C#.NET

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-resolution

I create windows application in C#.NET in resolution 1366x768 now I run this application in any another resolution like 1024x768 or 800x600 then it will not work on that resolution because all the control in the form will goes out of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the **Anchor** property of the controls you have in your windows form.

Answer (score 1):

Set Anchor/Dock property

Go through 
[How To Create a Resolution-Independent Form](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182070)